# Values need to copy from Col A to Col B in Excel without data loss

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

In my Excel, I have 2 columns For Ex: Col A & Col B.
In Col A I have 100 Records but in Col B having only 50 records that is scattered not in sequence.
I have to copy and paste the same information for missing in Col B from Col A.
When I put look up and tried to copy and paste the values it’s not coping the data correctly.
Can anyone please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Are you using spreadsheet formulae or VBA? Do you want to fill in the missing information in Column B, or are you making a new Column (for example, ColumnC) that contains (Column B) or (Column A if Column B is missing)?

Comment: No new column, I need to copy in Col B which missing information

Comment: Spreadsheet formula and User Defined Functions (UDF) cannot change the content of other cells or worksheet properties. You will need use VBA to accomplish this task.

Comment: Do we have any Formula to do this. Let me know

Comment: Can you provide an example of the existing data and an example of how you want the end result?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution using VBA. Here is the code used ...

```
Sub FillInMissing()
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Dim lstRow As Long, lstCol As Long
Dim iLoop As Long

    Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet6")
    lstRow = mySht.Range("A" & mySht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lstCol = mySht.Cells(1, mySht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    For iLoop = 1 To lstRow
        If Len(mySht.Cells(iLoop, 2).Value) = 0 Then
            mySht.Cells(iLoop, 2).Value = mySht.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
        End If
    Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Starting with data that looks like this ...

[image]

After the code runs, it looks like this ...

[image]